# merge data frame: get first value from the top from pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have data frame "df" with columns names- a to i.

[image: "df" dataframe]

After merging -

[image]

1. I need to merge records(sum column h values) together where account number(column i), date(column a), bank code(column g) are same. Example - Rows 21327 and 21328 should be merged into one with amount value in h = 3922.00; For this I use pivot table -

```
output = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['a','g','i'],values='h',aggfunc=['sum'])
output=output.reset_index()
```

Columns in output dataframe -

```
MultiIndex([(  'a',  ''),(  'g',  ''),(  'i',  ''),('sum', 'h')],)
```

1. Now I need to get back all other columns b,c,d,e,f but but these will have multiple records for a single account code (column i).
2. I need first value of these columns from original "df" under the
   condition - a,g,i in original dataframe "df" = a,g,i in output dataframe.
   Stuck here. I tried this but does not seem to help me. I tried grouypby also but still stuck.

```
output.columns = list(map("".join, output.columns))
```

```
df2 = output.merge(df.drop('h',axis=1), on='i', how='left')
```

```
df2.columns
```

```
Index(['d_x', 'e_x', 'g_x', 'i', 'sumh', 'a', 'b', 'c','d_y','e_y','f','g_y'],dtype='object')
```

P.S. "df" does not have unique values in any of the columns so I can not use them as index

Comment: Please post your tables as code rather than images so that we can recreate them and help you solve this.

Comment: Sorry I did not follow. 
Tables as codes?

Comment: If you put 3 tick marks (```) above and below a section of writing in your question, you can format it as code. Please post the code necessary to create the tables above.

Comment: Done edits now. I have tried many other grouypby codes but still can't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your meaning is a little unclear, but this is my best interpretation of what you're looking for.  If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [11012022, 'TT', '0000120461', 11012022, 'GUY A', 'GUY B', 'xxx', 3921.99, 'GD148001'],
        [11012022, 'TT', '0000130000', 11012022, 'GUY A', 'GUY B', 'xxx', 0.01,'GD148001'],
        [20012022, 'TT', '0000140000', 20012022, 'GUY A', 'GUY C', 'xxx', 6163.34, 'GD148001']
    ],
    columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
)

df_sum = df.groupby(['a','i'])['h'].sum().rename('sum_h')
df = df.merge(df_sum, left_on=['a', 'i'], right_index=True)

print(df)
```

This gives the output:

```
          a   b           c         d      e      f    g        h         i    sum_h
0  11012022  TT  0000120461  11012022  GUY A  GUY B  xxx  3921.99  GD148001  3922.00
1  11012022  TT  0000130000  11012022  GUY A  GUY B  xxx     0.01  GD148001  3922.00
2  20012022  TT  0000140000  20012022  GUY A  GUY C  xxx  6163.34  GD148001  6163.34
```

I think then you're saying that you're looking for only the first row per (a, g, i) group?  If so, then do this:

```
df_first = df.groupby(['a','g','i']).first().reset_index().sort_index(axis=1)

print(df_first)
```

Gives output:

```
          a   b           c         d      e      f    g        h         i    sum_h
0  11012022  TT  0000120461  11012022  GUY A  GUY B  xxx  3921.99  GD148001  3922.00
1  20012022  TT  0000140000  20012022  GUY A  GUY C  xxx  6163.34  GD148001  6163.34
```

If you want to output the data to a file readable by Excel, then

```
df_first.to_csv("FileName")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Troy. I have a question though.
What does this do? - df_first.to_string() and does this statement change df_string. From my understanding we need to assign it -> df_first = df_first.to_string()

When I print just df I get these columns - sum_h_x and sum_h_y columns

Comment: Also I need to print the final df_first to excel but I guess after I use to_string() it does not remain a dataframe. How do I do this?

Comment: @CodeBot print(df_first.to_string()) just prints the entire dataframe to your screen.  If you only do print(df_first) then it may cut off some of the output when it displays on your screen.  It's just for display purposes and has no actual impact on anything.  If it's confusing at all, just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly; you are just looking to group your df by 3 columns and based on that grouping aggregate one column to sum and the rest to get the first values.

```
columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

df.groupby(['a', 'g', 'i']) \
    .agg(
    b = ('b', 'first'),
    c = ('c', 'first'),
    d = ('d', 'first'),
    e = ('e', 'first'),
    f = ('f', 'first'),
    h = ('h', 'sum')
) \
.reset_index()[columns]
```

Output:
[image: output_dataframe]

`groupby` gets the columns you want to group by, `agg` gets columns you want to aggregate and how you want to aggregate them (first and sum for your case) and left part of the equation is just how you want to name the column after aggregation. Then we `reset_index` to keep group by columns that are in the index and use `[columns]` to order the columns to your preference.

Let me know if I am missing something.